# Jssor Slider: how to run with another jquery version on the same page

Tags: jquery, jssor

I am running Jquery version *jquery-1.7.2.min.js* because I am using [CssGrid](http://codecanyon.net/item/responsive-css-grid/4928861%22) to make the site responsive.

I'd also like to use the Jssor Slider, which uses the newer version of *jquery-1.9.1.min.js*.

I tried using the noConflict Jquery, but am not sure how to encase the rest of the code, so that it doesn't conflict.

```
    <!-- load jQuery 1.9.1 -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var jQuery_1_9_1 = $.noConflict(true);
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jssor.core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jssor.utils.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jssor.slider.js"></script>
```

I'm assuming I have to change the wording of the Slider script name, but am unsure how to rename/code it.

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
```

Cleaned up code of site without CSS [JFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sltyler1/cRfCk/).

So can someone point me in the right direction on how to change the code to make both versions run correctly with using the noConflict for Jquery? If I'm not mistaken I can just modify the one for Jssor Slider and then leave the older 1.7.2 alone and it will default to that version?

**Edit: Weirdly enough the responsive grid needs the jquery at the bottom of the page (and does seem to work with the newer version of Jquery), whereas the Jssor Slider needs it at the top? Odd, but I'll work around it.. Sorry for the wasting of space!**

Comment: your fiddle is a mess. you can't use html in the javascript panel, and you should load external resources from the side panel. follow some of the tips the tool is trying to give you.

Comment: also, you do _not_ need 2 versions of jquery. Unless the responsive grid is not compatible with a newer version of jquery (which I doubt, but I suppose is possible), and if that is the case, I would tell you to use a newer framework like [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Comment: Sorry didn't hit run, I'll try and clean that up. Yes, the responsive grid doesn't seem to be compatible with the newer version, which is the cause of using two the different versions. Sorry, didn't make that clear. I'll look into bootstrap, haven't actually ever used it, only glanced at it a few times. Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are very lucky that jssor slider works with any jquery version.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jssor.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jssor.utils.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jssor.slider.js"></script>
```